# Why is my question attracting down votes and close votes?

Tags: support

I have asked a [question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/8639/how-to-be-in-less-risky-and-most-profitable-situation-while-moving-from-top-most) on Workplace SE and am continually editing and modifying as per the users' suggestions. Still, some users are down-voting and voting to close without leaving any comments. I hate this behavior.

My specific questions are below:

- Why is this question attracting down votes?
- How can I improve my question in order to stop down votes and close votes further and attract positive up votes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### **Why is the question getting downvotes?**

You've made some edits so far yourself, and this is great! The challenge that I see remaining is that this is essentially a series of really broad questions lumped together all in one. I do think there is a problem to be solved here though, and I think that with some more edits, you can turn this into an upvoted question.

What research have you done so far yourself on what it's like to work for smaller companies? Perhaps the downvotes are because people may think you should be able to at least partially answer some of this yourself. I suggest doing a Google search on some techniques for determining if a small company is right for you, as well as some research techniques. If you encounter something that seems confusing or that you don't understand, include it in your question and ask about that instead.

In general, try to provide enough information and details so that the question can be answered without having to guess or hypothesize about what the job and company culture is. Every employer is different, and that may make this somewhat hard to answer.

Also, this avoids the game of 20 questions in the comments in order to find out the details about your situation. Again, I think you do have something here that could be edited, and I'd suggest starting with Google and then updating your question with the areas where you're stuck.

### **Voting without leaving a comment:**

I encourage people to give askers and answerers advice on how to improve the post by leaving nice, constructive comments. However, many people don't do this either because they aren't good at explaining these things or they've been treated badly by an asker or answerer who didn't take their advice so kindly.

To help encourage more people to leave comments on your post, it's best to be as neutral as possible when asking for feedback. In other words, show the community that you're not going to lash out as soon as they leave a comment. *I haven't seen you do that or be rude to anyone, but I mention it just to be thorough.* :)

**Here are some things I've done in the past that have been successful for me:**

- **Don't address the downvoters. Just ask in general**: "Hey, does anyone know what I can do to improve this post? I see someone downvoted it."  Chances are, other users who *didn't* downvote may have thought about it, or maybe they just have some helpful tips on what you can do to improve your post. Be open minded and friendly, and you'll find more people are responsive and willing to help.
- **If someone is rude to you, don't be rude back**; instead, remain calm and constructive. Otherwise, other people may wish to excuse themselves from any potential clashes, and this may limit the amount of helpful feedback you receive. Chances are, the person may seem rude as a defense mechanism, and if you're polite in response, you may just find that person warms up to you.

Remember, votes are anonymous, and no user is required to disclose whether or not he or she voted on your post. Besides, it just doesn't matter; you don't need the downvoters. There are more viewers on your question than there are downvoters, so there's plenty of other people who will give you good feedback.  Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @jmort253. I don't want to take downvote personally but I do, at least from time to time. But I do agree we need to remain constructive even if the others seems to be at fault.

Answer (score 3):

I am going to be blunt and honest here:

This is an English Language based Q&A.  Your question is badly worded and showed no effort to attempt to conform to SE standards when it was posted.  We have tried to help you correct this in the past by making edits but they were rebuked.

When you ask a question here the bare minimum expected is that the question be readable and show thought.  I think that your english skills combined with the way you ask the question make it difficult to understand and it appears like little effort was put in to making it understandable.  I suspect this is more of an appearance than reality but all we have to go on is the appearance.

The question you ask *"How to be safe and profitable..."*  I suspect this is another translation problem.  It does not really mean much to ask *that* question in the western culture in the realm of office work.  If you were talking about gold mining in Africa, or even construction or other physically perilous work then your question makes more sense to us.  I suggest you either find another translation or define what you mean by safe and profitable.  What are the risks you are concerned about?  What are the economic concerns that you have?

I suggest next time you ask a question you go to Chat and ask for help with the wording to get it squared away before it attracts large numbers of down votes.  You might even want to ask the question in chat first.  If you really want help there are several of us willing to help you.

Comment: +1 for the suggestion for chat. many of us spend a lot of time there and would be more than willing to help work out good questions. I think nearly all of us have done this ourselves for questions we've asked

Comment: @Chad: _We have tried to help you correct this in the past by making edits but they were rebuked._. The incident which you are referring is the incident where you totally changed the question and my intentions. FYI, SE guidelines instructs that editing question should not change the overall meaning and intentions of the question. Hence I have REDIRECT your edits towards question real intentions as conforming to the SE guidelines and NOT REBUKE you edits. Hence I request you please change your opinion about that incident. For further discussion on that incident please open private chat room

Comment: @Ramya - There is no need to have a discussion you asked why... I am trying to help you understand why.  It is not just one question either it happened on a couple of them.

Comment: Hi @Chad, you can be honest without being blunt ;)

Comment: @Andyk - Blunt is effective.  It was not rude and being that the OP is not a native speaker beating around the bush can have the effect of miscommunication.  So politely take your comment and use it constructively somewhere else. (See I can be indirect and still communicate my meaning when it is called for)